# Regex for special char

Tags: regex

Can anyone help to get a regex build for below input string,I need to extract the the data which is marked `☒`.
Eg:-

Input text:-

```
☐I am good
☐This is sky
☒Nice to meet you
☐hello world
```

Output :-
    Nice to meet you

Comment: What flavour/app are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
^☒.+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/xrSNv7/1/).

---

If you happen to have it in one line, you may use

```
☒[^☐\n]+
```

See [**another demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/nMnz9H/1/).

Comment: It doesn't work if string is in one line.

☐I am good ☐This is sky ☒Nice to meet you ☐hello world

Comment: @prateekjain: No, it doesn't. There's an anchor `^` which fixes the expression to the start of a line.

Comment: @prateekjain: See the updated answer.